# Finding players that played with another player that has appeared twice

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
team1
+----------+----------+
| id1      | name     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | a        |
| 2        | b        |
| 3        | c        |
+----------+----------+

team2
+----------+----------+
| id2      | name     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | d        |
| 2        | e        |
| 3        | f        |
+----------+----------+

play
+----------+----------+----------+
| id3      | id1      | id2      |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | 1        | 1        |
| 2        | 1        | 3        |
| 3        | 2        | 1        |
| 4        | 3        | 2        |
| 5        | 2        | 3        |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I'm new to sql. I am struggling with how to set a counting condition. Let's say for the tables above, I want to find a player from team1 who plays with a player from team2 that has played or will play at least two times total. So basically, if a value from id2 shows up more than once, then any value from id1 that plays against id2 should be part of the result. Just by looking at the table, I would want it to return id1 = 1 and id1 = 2 if it was without redundancies. I can't wrap my head around how to go about this.

Comment: that is a weird (bad) data structure. surely you should have only one player table, and have both id1 and id2 refer to the one table. with your design, players can only play against someone from the other table.

Comment: I edited the tables to be teams. Hopefully that makes it a little clearer... I probably could have thought up of a better example...

Comment: then `team_id` should be added as a column on player. there should be only one "player" table. You're headed for trouble otherwise

Comment: You're right. But for the sake of learning more about different queries, I just made up this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select distinct p1.id1
from play p1
join (select id2
      from play
      group by id2
      having count(*) > 1) p2
on p1.id2 = p2.id2
```